# Vertical Bar chart using rotation='vertical' not working

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

From the matplot lib example [lines_bars_and_markers](http://matplotlib.org/examples/lines_bars_and_markers/barh_demo.html)
using `rotation='vertical'` does not make it vertical. What am I doing wrong?

```
"""
Simple demo of a horizontal bar chart.
"""
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.rcdefaults()
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


# Example data
people = ('Tom', 'Dick', 'Harry', 'Slim', 'Jim')
y_pos = np.arange(len(people))
performance = 3 + 10 * np.random.rand(len(people))
error = np.random.rand(len(people))

plt.barh(y_pos, performance, xerr=error, align='center', alpha=0.4)
plt.yticks(y_pos, people)
plt.xlabel('Performance')
plt.title('How fast do you want to go today?')

plt.show()
rotation='vertical'
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`barh` is for horizontal bar charts, change to `bar` and then swap around the data for the axes. You can't simply write `rotation='vertical'` because that isn't telling the `matplotlib` library anything, it's just creating a string that is never used.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.rcdefaults()
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


# Example data
people = ('Tom', 'Dick', 'Harry', 'Slim', 'Jim')
x_pos = np.arange(len(people))
performance = 3 + 10 * np.random.rand(len(people))
error = np.random.rand(len(people))

plt.bar(x_pos, performance, yerr=error, align='center', alpha=0.4)
plt.xticks(x_pos, people)
plt.ylabel('Performance')
plt.title('How fast do you want to go today?')

plt.show()
```

Comment: @Perlinn Change it to 0.1, rerun and find out in 2 seconds flat :) If you feel that this answer has solved your problem then please consider marking it as correct so that people know the issue is not still open.

Comment: @Perlinn The more bland answer to your question is to check the [docs](http://matplotlib.org/api/artist_api.html#matplotlib.artist.Artist.set_alpha). Alpha is used to set transparency. 0 is transparent, 1 is opaque and you can pick values in between. Setting it to 1 in this case would obscure the lower portion of the error bars.

Comment: what is this for? error = np.random.rand(len(people))

Comment: @Perlinn delete it from the code and remove `yerr=error,`, then re-run and look at the graph. Your computer will _not_ explode and you will see the difference for yourself. I'm answering like this because everything I know about programming is self-taught in a reasonably short space of time, and the **key** skill to understanding is knowing how to explore these things yourself. If there's things you don't understand, brute-force Google searches and try and get an answer. If all fails, use Stack Overflow.

Comment: got it! removed it anyway as its not helpful to me

Comment: @Perlinn great that you got to the bottom of it :)